# Sort posts by custom taxonomy and custom field ASC

Tags: php, sorting, wordpress

i tried to sort my post by a custom taxonomy, but it doesn't do it correctly.

I try to sort it by the custom field named "niveau_academique" created with ACF.

I tried to simply include it with

```
$clauses['orderby'] = " niveau_academique ";
$clauses['orderby'] .= ( 'ASC' == strtoupper( $wp_query->get('order') ) ) ? 'ASC' : 'DESC';
```

But i it shows no results. Theres, my actual sorting function.

```
function projets_clauses( $clauses, $wp_query ) {
global $wpdb;

if ( isset( $wp_query->query['orderby'] ) && 'degres' == $wp_query->query['orderby'] ) {

    $clauses['join'] .= " LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT object_id, GROUP_CONCAT(name ORDER BY name ASC) AS degres
        FROM $wpdb->term_relationships
        INNER JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy USING (term_taxonomy_id)
        INNER JOIN $wpdb->terms USING (term_id)
        WHERE taxonomy = 'degres'
        GROUP BY object_id
    ) AS degres_terms ON ($wpdb->posts.ID = degres_terms.object_id)";
    $clauses['orderby'] = " degres_terms.degres ";
    $clauses['orderby'] .= ( 'ASC' == strtoupper( $wp_query->get('order') ) ) ? 'ASC' : 'DESC';
}

return $clauses;
}
add_filter( 'posts_clauses', 'projets_clauses', 10, 2 );
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve my question with this answer.

```
function orderby( $a, $b ) {
    global $posts;
    $apos   = get_field('niveau_academique', $a->ID);
    $bpos   = get_field('niveau_academique', $b->ID);
    return ( $apos < $bpos ) ? -1 : 1;
}
usort( $projets->posts, "orderby" );
```

Answer (score 0):

check last executed query in wordpress to see your modified query is added in wordpress post clause or not.

check also for posts_clauses

http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/posts_clauses

```
<?php echo $GLOBALS['wp_query']->request; ?>
```

Comment: Got this: 
SELECT wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id) LEFT JOIN ( SELECT object_id, GROUP_CONCAT(name ORDER BY name ASC) AS degres FROM wp_term_relationships INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy USING (term_taxonomy_id) INNER JOIN wp_terms USING (term_id) WHERE taxonomy = 'degres' GROUP BY object_id ) AS degres_terms ON (wp_posts.ID = degres_terms.object_id) WHERE 1=1 AND wp_posts.post_type = 'projet' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish') AND (wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'date_de_debut' ) GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY degres_terms.degres ASC